# VB.NET Conversion from type 'DBNull' to type 'Decimal' is not valid when field has data

Tags: .net, database, vb.net

I have been looking for a solution to this problem for a while now and am feeling really stuck; I can find solutions to problems that are similar, but not the same as mine.

I am pulling data from a local MSSQL database using a stored procedure, then send the data to a web service. Every part of the component works well except for a pesky problem will a `DBNull` being returned from the `DataRow` field, when I know that the field is not null and has valid data. The database and associated `INSERT` statements that add to this field  are designed to not allow `NULL` entries. When I debug break the program on or right before the line that throws the error I see that the field has valid data for the current row.
If I add a null check to the code (as below) the operation continues as normal:

```
        Dim dataResultsTable = Me.myViewTableAdapter.GetData(int)

        For Each myDataRow In dataResultsTable.Rows
                        If worker.CancellationPending Then
                            e.Cancel = True
                        Else
                            If myDataRow.Item("syncd") = 0 Then
                               If IsDBNull(myDataRow.Item("bidamount")) Then
                                  _bidAmt = ""
                               Else
    // With out the null check this line throws an error
                                  _bidAmt = myDataRow.Item("bidamount") 
                               End If    

                               If IsDBNull(myDataRow.Item("date_time")) Then
                                  _dateTime = ""
                               Else
    // With out the null check this line throws an error
                                  _dateTime = myDataRow.Item("date_time")
                               End If

// . . . . . . . . 

                               worker.ReportProgress(percentcomplete)
                            End If
                         End If
                      Next
```

The question here is: Why is the read operation returning `DBNull` instead of the data in the database? Any and all help here is much appreciated!

**EDIT:** Just to be clear, the operation does return the proper data, but the data is not being saved into the variable.

Comment: Demonstrate how you know that the data is returning non-null values. Unrelated to the question, but you should add an `Exit For` after the `e.Cancel = True`

Comment: Thanks @JoelCoehoorn, I missed that one and I am usually pretty good at that kind of thing.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn, When I break execution of the program around the `If worker.CancellationPending Then` statement, and then expand the value of the `dataResultsTable` variable I see that those fields that throw an error has values in them. I'm stumped on this one, it should work by all accounts that I can see. (Only come across this situation once before)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is only a suggestion. In order not to use `IsDBNull`, why don't you alter your `Stored Procedure` by converting default value for `Null` fields using `COALESCE`

For example:

```
SELECT COALESCE(bidamount,''), -- this will convert null value into empty one
       COALESCE(date_time,''), ..... 
FROM .....
```

as with your code `_bidAmt = ""` and `_dateTime = ""`

```
                    If worker.CancellationPending Then
                        e.Cancel = True
                    Else
                        If myDataRow.Item("syncd") = 0 Then
                              _bidAmt = myDataRow.Item("bidamount")    
                              _dateTime = myDataRow.Item("date_time")
                        End If
                           worker.ReportProgress(percentcomplete)
                        End If
                     End If
```

Comment: This is a good approach, but the question of why the result set contains data and not DBNull but the `.item` method returns DBNull is the question. The data is there, but it is returned as null for some reason. But I am going to put your suggestion in my pocket for later, I come across that situation semi-often. Thank you @john

Comment: although you didn't exactly answer the original question, I marked your answer as accepted because you had the answer to another related problem I was having before I had it! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Another suggestion is to use the Field method of the DataRow along with nullable types.

For example, if the column in the database is a decimal, you can use something like this:

```
decimal? _bidAmt = myDataRow.Field<decimal?>("bidamount");
```

This way, NULL values in the database will be handled properly.

BTW:  I hope you are not storing dates in your database using strings as your code seems to imply!!